# Python Regex Named Groups

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently trying to solve a problem splitting following string

```
[@x arg-xa, arg. xb, arg xc @y arg-ya, arg. yb, arg yc @z arg-za, arg. zb, arg zc]
```

into some kind of structured dict object. A result like the following list would be appreciated:

```
[
    {
        'command': 'x',
        'args': ['arg-xa', 'arg. xb', 'arg xc']
    },
    {
        'command': 'y',
        'args': ['arg-ya', 'arg. yb', 'arg yc']
    }
    {
        'command': 'z',
        'args': ['arg-za', 'arg. zb', 'arg zc']
    }
]
```

The command is prefixed with an "@" sign, the following arguments for the command are separated by a "," sign.
Splitting the string with string.split('@') and some loops would work, but I'm wondering if it would be possible to solve this with one single regex.

Maybe some regex master would be so kind and show me the light!

As always, thank's a lot.
(I used the search, but haven't found a solution for this kind of problem)

Comment: This pretty weird regex: `\@(?P<command>\w+)(?P<arg>,\s?[\w\s-]+)\@?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use `.split()` and cut the string up:

```
import string

s = '@x arg-xa, arg. xb, arg xc @y arg-ya, arg. yb, arg yc @z arg-za, arg. zb, arg zc'

result = []

for part in s.split('@')[1:]:  # `[1:]` skips the first (empty) element
    command, _, arguments = part.partition(' ')

    result.append({
        'command': command,
        'args': map(string.strip, arguments.split(', '))
    })
```

Comment: Yeah, it does work - I don't use Python much. I think it can be improved a bit by trimming spaces, though.

Comment: @Blender Thank's for your solution! Really appreciate it. But I know that it works with string.split method and loops. I was specificaly interested in a regex. Sure, your's is working and if no regex comes up, I'm happy to accept your answer...

Comment: @Blender: There are some excessive space at the end of last argument of the 1st and 2nd item in result.

Comment: @hetsch: You won't be able to do it with just regex.

Comment: @Blender Think you are right. Trying now for some time, but no result. Really like your solution. Thank's again for your help, accepted!

Comment: @Blender: I think it is possible with just regex - just provide replacement function to `sub` with closure, and an appropriate regex. But I think the straightforward solution above is much cleaner.

Comment: @nhahtdh This was also my idea. My problem was to find a working repeating pattern for the arguments.